# Why did Rodney say, "A Tic Tac wouldn't kill you"?

Tags: doctor-dolittle, dr-dolittle-1998

Funny fantasy movie *Dr.Dolittle (1998)*

Rodney, the talking guinea pig watches hatching of 
Swan's egg and says to McGruff, the talking dog:

> I see some shakin' in that egg. I see shakin' in  the egg. Hey, how's
>   it goin', McGruff? You know what?  **A Tic Tac wouldn't kill you**.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dogs can have notoriously bad breath.  A [Tic Tac](https://www.tictacusa.com/en/) is a brand of breath mint.  It's just a joke that if you have a stinky dog that can speak and understand English, you can tell him to eat a breath mint.

Comment: I added the movie tag because I'm pretty sure the books don't have any plugs for Tic Tacs.